# Can I Auto-Launch My Flutter App Alongside With Another App?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build an app that auto-launches alongside specific user-chosen apps. No luck finding info on this – seeking guidance!

Some people told me that it's possible with Kotlin but I'm trying to make it with flutter.

Comment: It’s possible with native code. https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-autostart-own-Android-app-when-another-app-of-my-choice-launches